# SEO Website with links only

Tags: search, seo, search-engine, pagerank

I have a website that contains links to other sites only.
They link to an image gallery or a video.
Does google accepts this or will it penalize my site because I don't have any real content?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google does look for human generated content. They also look for the links to your site. I would add stuff to your site and also guest blog etc to get traffic to your site.